# home servers - home wireless router

Tags: router, switch, wireless-networking

I have 4 servers that I run from my house, each one is running separate services such as apache, mysql etc.

All 4 servers are connected to a standard home wireless router that currently works as firewall. My question is, could the "D-Link" wireless router make the connection slower for people trying to access websites on my servers? or should I get something more specific that will perform better?

Any recommendations? Average traffic is about 7-8K different users/month, about 50K hits/week

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It shouldn't.  You would need to post specifics regarding the bandwidth of your connection, throughput of the router, etc to give a precise answer.

However, assuming you have your servers connected via a wired interface to the router, I would bet your connection to the Internet (cable, dsl, ...) is far slower than the 100Mbps or 1000 Mbps of your wired router connection.  Basically, assuming you have a normal residential connection, the bottleneck will be at your connection to your ISP, not your internal network.

Even if they are connected to the wireless interface (not good for reliability and speed), if you have a fast enough wireless network, you would still be outpacing the normal residential connection.

Comment: current connection is 20M/2M